# Internet Explorer shows deny icon over select options if the options flow over a disabled input

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form with multiple dropdowns that depends one on each other. When I open a dropdown over some other disabled input the acces deny icon is shown. This is only in Internet Explorer (of course).

I am using Bootstrapjs 3. Is there any CSS fix for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because your “problem description” doesn’t include _any_ usable specifics/information, I can only guess that this might be an issue similar to the one discussed here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911035/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-the-pointer-cursor-from-interacting-with-elements-behi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a known open bug in Internet Explorer 11.](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/963961)

There's no good simple or non-hacky workaround besides getting rid of the not-allowed cursor everywhere by overriding Bootstrap's CSS.