# Select element overlaps anchor, mouse flickering, in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I' am using an anchor after a select element.

```
<select>
<option>option 1</option>
<option>option 2</option>
<option>option 3</option>
</select>
<br />
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

If I move the the mouse over the first option the cursor changes between default and pointer because of the anchor.

How can I avoid this? I only want to have the default cursor.

Comment: When I put that into a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/xfr1hL05/), I don't see the issue you're describing. Can you post a more complete example, that does demonstrate the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23648834/1427878, http://stackoverflow.com/q/27911035/1427878

Comment: I added a break row so the link is under the selectbox.

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
  cursor: default;
}
a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <option>option 3</option>
</select>
<br />
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I only focused on the selectbox.